# Using Foreign Data Wrappers in PostgreSQL (variable filename)

Tags: postgresql, csv, foreign-data-wrapper

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3 and want to import some daily generated csv files into specific tables.
I started playing with FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) and pointed to a specific csv, where I can query and append/upsert to a table. 
But I have two more needs:
 - The file generation date and source branch is present in the filename, and only there. 
   I need to get this information and insert also in the table.
 - As expected, the files names are not fixed, so the FDW doesn't know where to get the information.

I thought about solving this using some unix tools (although my Postgres runs on windows), basically for each file in a list (from a previously created index), the script would rename the file and pass the branch and date as parameters to a psql.exe command line, where the import would be from a fixed name in FDW.

This would work, but this script sound a bit like a hack and not a very "elegant" solution. 
Does anyone has an better suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked SQL `COPY` or psql `\copy` commands? They might be easier and faster than FDW.

Comment: The method of input is quite similar using \copy or FDW, and it would save one or two operations in the script. But still would place most of the "intelligence" on the script itself.